# Tensor product by the canonical module preserves Cohen-Macaulayness

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, cohen-macaulay-rings

Let $X$ be a $\mathbb{Q}$-Gorenstein variety of dimension at least $2$. Suppose that $X$ is normal and Cohen-Macaulay with at worst isolated singularities. Let $F$ be a maximal Cohen-Macaulay $\mathcal{O}_X$-module and $\omega_X$ denotes the canonical module/dualizing sheaf on $X$. Is $F \otimes \omega_X$ also Cohen-Macaulay?

Comment: Are you sure you want tensor product and not Hom?

Comment: At least when $X$ is affine, the following is known: Let $R$ be a $d$-dimensional local CM ring with an isolated singularity, admitting a canonical module $\omega$. Let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module. Then, $M\otimes_R\omega$ is maximal Cohen-Macaulay if and only if $\text{Ext}_R^{1\le j \le d}(M,R)=0$. But are you asking for $M\otimes_R\omega$ to be just Cohen-Macaulay instead of maximal Cohen-Macaulay?